# maxSize in ckfinder config file doesn't work

Tags: php, ckfinder

I use ckfinder version 2.0.

The problem is that maxSize attribute doesn't work!
Here is my resource type configuration.

```
$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
    'name' => 'Files',              // Single quotes not allowed
    'url' => $baseUrl . 'files',
    'directory' => $baseDir . 'files',
    'maxSize' => "10M",
    'allowedExtensions' => '7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip',
    'deniedExtensions' => '');

$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
    'name' => 'Images',
    'url' => $baseUrl . 'images',
    'directory' => $baseDir . 'images',
    'maxSize' => "10M",
    'allowedExtensions' => 'bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png',
    'deniedExtensions' => '');

$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
    'name' => 'Flash',
    'url' => $baseUrl . 'flash',
    'directory' => $baseDir . 'flash',
    'maxSize' => "10M",
    'allowedExtensions' => 'swf,flv',
    'deniedExtensions' => '');
```

But still get "too big file" error.

Comment: Perhaps it's PHP that's giving you this error? PHP also has a maximum size: [check this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/)

Comment: Yeah,It was due to PHP maximum size

Comment: Yet another comment that should have been an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need permission to access the php.ini file on the server.
In the php.ini you will find the line `upload_max_filesize`. 
You can set this to `upload_max_filesize=10M` and then restart the webserver.

It work for me.